# Short Emmet abbreviations do not work for css/scss

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, emmet

- VSCode Version: 1.5.2
- OS Version: Ubuntu 16.04
- My `settings.json`

  ```
  {
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
    "editor.tabCompletion": true
  }
  ```

  When I try to use Emmet shortcuts in CSS / SCSS, for example:
  [image]

  And I hit tab to complete, I get this:
  [image]

Instead of `color`, similar behaviour with `bg`. I did find hackish solution: `"editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": "500"`. But would like to know if there are some better solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change your key bindings with the following:

(Menu: Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts)

```
{ "key": "enter", "command": "acceptSelectedSuggestion",
                  "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible" },
{ "key": "tab", "command": "editor.emmet.action.expandAbbreviation",
                  "when": "config.emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab && editorTextFocus && !editorHasSelection && !editorReadonly && !editorTabMovesFocus" }
```

The only problem is, to accept any suggestion from intellisense you'll have to use `enter` instead of `tab` from now on.